# how to write xml to a stream a network of beans in a memory efficient way

Tags: java, xml, memory, xml-serialization, jdom

Editing to specify more clearly the scenario.

I have to write a xml file, the info comes from **several** beans (not even whole bean, jsut subset of some of them), some of the beans contain lists etc. So I cannot just give xstream one root bean and let it write the xml. Also some formatting might need to fulfill some conditions, but the previous issue is the one

Right now I am using JDOM to create the doc in memory, and eventually I use a XMLOutputter to write the doc to a file.

But the beans I want to write can have very large lists of other beans etc, and the memory used can be quite high.

So I suspect there should be a better way in terms of memory? 
I already create the xml for some beans inside the larger bean with xstream and append them as Elements to the JDOM.

I was hoping the same way its more memory efficient to parse xml using a pull parser, the same could be apply to writing xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight:
You start off with a tree of beans. You wish to use these to construct an XML document following their structure but with its own syntax/schema so simple bean XML serialization is out of the question...

If that is so, JAXB as recommended by Blaise Doughan is a good suggestion. If, however, you require a much finer control over the XML formatting, you need to do some highly specific serialization, or perhaps you wish to remove some bean references while creating the XML to allow garbage collection during the execution, then the Streaming API for XML (StAX) might be what you need. You can write XML constructs to a stream with it.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html

Sorry if it isn't exactly what you meant. If I'm getting it wrong, could you give us a small usage scenario?

Comment: edited my question to try to clarify

Comment: First option: you could write out to a stream using StAX. Class XMLStreamWriter should come in handy. You'd need to do some minor reading regarding the use of StAX. Should you be familiar with the Java XML APIs, it'll be easy. An XMLStreamWriter is created with another stream, so you can drop to the underlying stream for some parts if needed. Just use some flushing to make sure the XML stuff was already written to it. Considering you already convert your beans to JDOM structures, this is probably not a huge adaptation.

Comment: Second option: using JAXB. Does more stuff for you, but is more complex and might not be entirely suitable to what you're trying to do. A JAXB Marshaller, which generates XML from beans, can be set to create an XML fragment rather than a whole document. You could use this to assemble a document. I think StAX is more interesting in your case. It has filled the long standing gap of a standard XML "writer" for Java. JDOM is nice to use but a memory hog. DOM APIs make document construction simple, but you'll have large datastructures in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Xstream, a xml serialization library?

Comment: XStream's url: http://xstream.codehaus.org/

It's also really easy to use.

Comment: yes, no setup required in most cases (and very easy to add customizations if needed)

Comment: Have you considered using JAXB instead?: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: nice comparison; of course JAXB has the advantage of being a standard library, included in the JRE.
But what about performances? Have you benchmarked them?

Comment: JAXB can in some cases gobble up quite a bit of memory, I've noticed. But then again it uses StAX behind the curtains (at least, the reference implementation has a dependency on it afaik).

Comment: @Riccardo Cossu - JAXB is a standard that has one implementation (Metro) in the JRE.  There are also other implementations including:  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) and Apache JaxMe:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html

Comment: @G_H, @Riccardo Cossu - JAXB initializes its metadata at when the JAXBContext is created this improve execution time, but increase memory usage when compared to a serialization strategy like XStream. Profiling is really required when making decisions based on performance.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - Yup, JAXB does some heavy lifting that is more suitable to some situations than others. I've also found it a lot more useful when you start from a W3C XML Schema and want to represent it as beans, rather than having existing Java classes and wish to turn these into a distinct XML representation. It is possible, but mapping XML concepts to Java ones is easier than the other way around.

Comment: @G_H - Check out how EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) makes it even easier to start from Java objects:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550740/how-to-write-xml-to-a-stream-a-network-of-beans-in-a-memory-efficient-way/5553083#5553083

Comment: An XPath-based annotation?! I must say that is rather... sexy. In fact, if I had known such a thing two years ago a particular projects might've been several factors easier. I'm gonna have to check EclipseLink anyway since I'm looking for JPA alternatives to Hibernate. EDIT: OMG the conditional mapping! I'd understand XML to beans, but it even works the other way? Get me a tissue :p

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/

Comment: There has not been a release of Betwixt in 5 years.

Comment: I know. But this library is pretty stable and it does the basic stuff very well.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult using JDOM, even if you want to dig in and write customized sub classes. XMLOutputter sort of assumes that it is given a complete tree that it can traverse. To save memory, you must somehow arrange so that only the current sub-tree exist. It is quite feasible to chop off the sub trees that has been traversed; but how do you postpone the creation of sub trees until they are needed. All this is going to require some kind of coordination between the sub classed XMLOutputter, your specialized Element and your bean navigation code. Probably not worth the effort.

I, as G_H also does, would recommend taking a look at Stax, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter in combination with your own "bean navigator".

Answer (score 0):

**Declaration of Bias** - I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead

---

Using [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) you may be able to get the formatting you need.  This will allow you to eliminate the JDOM piece in order to reduce the memory footprint.

**Example**

Assuming we have the following class in our model (accessors omitted to save space):

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    private Address billingAddress;

    private Address shippingAddress;

}
```

***JAXB Mapping***

Since [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) is compliant with the JAXB specification ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) it will produce the following document by default:

```
<customer>
    <billingAddress/>
    <shippingAddress/>
</customer>
```

***Path Mapping***

If you require fine grain control over your XML you can use MOXy's @XmlPath extension.
Annotating the fields as follows:

```
@XmlPath("contact-info/billing-address")
private Address billingAddress;

@XmlPath("contact-info/shipping-address")
private Address shippingAddress;
```

Will cause the following XML to be produced:

```
<customer>
   <contact-info>
      <billing-address/>
      <shipping-address/>
   </contact-info>
</customer>
```

***Positional Mapping***

The XPath fragments can include a positional indicator:

```
@XmlPath("address[1]")
private Address billingAddress;

@XmlPath("address[2]")
private Address shippingAddress;
```

The resulting XML will look like:

```
<customer>
   <address/>
   <address/>
</customer>
```

***Conditional Mapping***

```
@XmlPath("address[@type='billing']")
private Address billingAddress;

@XmlPath("address[@type='shipping']")
private Address shippingAddress;
```

And the resulting XML will be:

```
<customer>
   <address type="billing"/>
   <address type="shipping"/>
</customer>
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html